# Why are my tiles not swapping in my slidepuzzle game, what is wrong with my javascript?

Tags: javascript

here are all my variables. i did't use the gridSize but i will use it later when im trying to resize the gameBoard.
for now i just want it to work with the 3 by 3 grid.
the tiles are just not swapping like i want them to but i cant seem to find the error.

```
let rows = 3;
let columns = 3;
//let gridSize = 3
let currentTile; //the clicked tile
let blankTile; //the blank tile
let turns = 0;

//let imgOrder = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let imgOrder = ["2", "6", "3", "9", "5", "8", "4", "1", "7"]

window.onload = function() {
    for (let r=0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (let c=0; c < cloumns; c++) {

            let tile = document.createElement("img");
            tile.id = r.toString() + "-" + c.toString();
            tile.src = imgOrder.shift() + ".jpg";

            tile.addEventListener("dragStart", dragStart);
            tile.addEventListener("dragHover", dragHover);
            tile.addEventListener("dragEnter", dragEnter);
            tile.addEventListener("dragLeave", dragLeave);
            tile.addEventListener("dragDrop", dragDrop);
            tile.addEventListener("dragEnd", dragEnd);
            
            document.getElementById("gameBoard").append(tile);
        }
    }
}

//here are all the functions for the drag and drop events

function dragStart() {
    currentTile = this; //while Tile is being dragged
}

function dragHover(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //while hovering over another tile
}

function dragEnter(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //while entering the tile you want to swap with
}

function dragLeave() {
                        //taking a tile and leave the original position
}

function dragDrop() {
    blankTile = this; //when the dragged image is beeing dopped on the blank Image/blankTile
}

function dragEnd() {
    let currentImg = currentTile.src;
    let blankImg = blankTile.src;

    currentTile.src = blankImg;
    blankTile.src = currentImg;
}
```

i tried to make different eventlisteners for every state of the drag and drop of the tiles but somehow they still don't swap

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i was actually able to answer my question myself.

```js
tile.addEventListener("dragDrop", dragDrop);
```

this line cant work unless you put in `"drop"` instead of `"dragdrop"`.
If you put in drop you can move and drop the tiles(and obviously swap the tiles).